# Related tab shows up twice - CRM 2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

When I go into existing case, and click on the chevron, the "Related Cases" tabs shows up twice. Would you be able to help? I have a javascript for the cases form but it doesn't have anything to do with the associated view.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Business Process Flow may have the duplicate. When you say the "Related Cases" tab shows up twice are you saying that you are seeing two stages that are both named "Related Cases"? For example, [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vamcq.png) has two stages displayed, Qualify and Develop. Or do you see "Related Cases" as duplicate steps within a stage?

Either way, you can view the details of the Business Process Flow, as long as you have the appropriate permissions, by navigating to Settings -> Processes and changing the view to "Business Process Flows". You can sort the view by the Primary Entity and you should see at least one where the primary entity is Case. Once you open the record you can see all of the stages and steps. A user with the appropriate privileges can edit this Business Process Flow as needed.

[Edit business process flows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531135(v=crm.7).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel. It turns out that I had to change the relationship behavior at an entity level.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean the duplicate "Navigation link" Related cases showing in top Jewel within the Case record.

You might have added a subgrid in Case form in addition to Existing 'Related case' associated view. You can verify this by doing below steps.

Open Case entity Form in 'Form Editor' & click 'Navigation' from top ribbon - 
inside 'Form editor'. Then focus on one of the left navigation link 'Related cases' & delete it.

Or double click the left navigation in 'Form editor' twice to focus the left hyperlink & delete it.